# Single directory pointing to multiple git repositories

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I am working in software vendor company. My team needs to submit code to client's git repository and we conduct code review prior submitting code in which we will have all the comments and code correction.To setup this flow,
I want to point parent project directory to multiple git repositories

How can I set up two git repositories in the same directory on osx. I am using sourcetree as git tool

Comment: looks like you needs [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Note that as I (and the current answer) understand this, it is *not* "multiple repositories in the same directory".  It's one (local) repo connecting to multiple remotes.  This is a fairly mainstream usage pattern for git.  When you say "two git repositories in the same directory", this suggests that you want two local repos to share a working tree directory - which you might, with considerable effort, be able to set up, but is really not a good idea.

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up multiple push URLs to a single remote.

Origin is default remote in a git project:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@git.company.es:group1/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@git.company.es:group1/project.git (push)
```

Then you can add more push url to your remote.

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git@git.other.es:test/project.git
```

Now you should show two (push) URLs and one (fetch) URL. Something like this:
    git remote -v
    origin  git@git.company.es:group1/project.git (fetch)
    origin  git@git.company.es:group1/project.git (push)
    origin  git@git@git.other.es:test/project.git (push)

Pushing to this remote will push to both upstreams simultaniously. Fetch and pull from this remote will still pull from the original repo only.

Also you can keep the original remote (origin) and create an alternative remote and use it to push both repositories:

```
git remote add both
git remote set-url --add --push both 
git@git.company.es:group_1/project.git
git remote set-url --add --push both git@git.other.es:test/project.git
```

And your remote configuration will be:

```
git remote -v
origin  git@git.company.es:group1/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@git.company.es:group1/project.git (push)
both    git@git.company.es:group1/project.git (fetch)
both    git@git.company.es:group1/project.git (push)
both    git@git@git.other.es:test/project.git (push)
```

And now you can decide which remote you want to use in different situations.