# Git command for multiple git repositories in a single directory - GIT_DIR

Tags: bash, git

I used [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910773/single-directory-pointing-to-multiple-git-repositories) on StackOverflow to figure out how to have a single directory which is populated from two git repositories, in my case `.org-git-work` and `org-git-personal` (this is needed so I can use some software that's fussy about having all of its files together, and so I can keep personal and professional materials apart).

Now I am trying to make aliases to interact with the two git repositories in this shared work directory, but somehow I'm not managing to convey the `GIT_DIR` in the alias.  Can anyone correct the following:

```
alias org-git-work='GIT_DIR=/foo/org/.work-org-git && echo $GIT_DIR && GIT_WORK_DIR=/foo/org && git'
```

when I try to use the above alias, `git` still looks in `.git`, instead of using the value of `GIT_DIR`:

```
org-git-work commit -m "Resource for preposterior sampling." bar.org
/foo/org/.work-org-git
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

...but the output from `echo` seems to indicate that it is set correctly.

Comment: You're probably not exporting the variables. say `export GIT_DIR=/foo/org/.work-org-git`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Environment variables, generally

You are conflating environment variables with shell variables.  (This is not surprising since the shells themselves do this to some extent.)  An *environment* variable is passed from the shell into programs that the shell runs, while a *shell* variable is not.

To set a shell variable, use `name=value` anywhere.

To set an *environment* variable for the duration of a single command, use the syntax `name=variable command`:

```
GIT_DIR=/foo/org/.work-org-git git ...
```

Do not use:

```
GIT_DIR=/foo/.org/.work-org-git && git ...
```

as this will merely set a *shell* variable.

To illustrate the difference, we can use `python -c`:

```
$ python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("FOO"))'
None
$ FOO=bar python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("FOO"))'
bar
$ FOO=bar && python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("FOO"))'
None
```

Initially, there is no environment setting for FOO.  Using the syntax *without* the `&&` operator, there is one, and using the syntax *with* the `&&` operator, it has once again vanished.

To set an environment variable and have the setting persist, use the `export` keyword.  There are several ways to do this:

```
FOO=bar export foo
```

or:

```
export FOO=bar
```

or:

```
FOO=bar; export FOO
```

all work.  Once the variable has been explicitly exported, *changes* to the variable are also exported:

```
$ export FOO=bar && python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("FOO"))'
bar
$ python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("FOO"))'
bar
```

To *remove* the environment variable, use `unset`:

```
$ unset FOO
$ python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("FOO"))'
None
```

#### Git's environment variables, specifically

The two variables you intend to fiddle with are `GIT_DIR` (one of the two you are using here) and `GIT_WORK_TREE` (not `GIT_WORK_DIR`).  So you really want:

```
GIT_DIR=path1 GIT_WORK_TREE=path2 git ...
```

You don't *have* to do it this way: the `git` front end command has arguments `--git-dir=path` and `--work-tree=path`, so you can write:

```
git --git-dir=path1 --work-tree=path2 ...
```

#### Caveat

Git really only understands a single repository at a time, which contains *every* commit with *every* snapshot of *every* file.  This singular repository containing everything has one (1) standard built-in *index*, which is also called its *staging area* or sometimes its *cache*.  This index / staging-area indexes / caches one (1) work-tree.<sup>1</sup>  Trying to extract two separate Git repositories into a single work-tree is going to cause a lot of headaches, as you will have two repositories sharing the one work-tree, so you will have two separate index files that both think they are in complete command of what's going on *in* that work-tree.

It's not that this won't work (it can), it's just that you're going to experience annoyances with this setup.

---

<sup>1</sup>In newer Git versions (2.5+) you can add additional work-trees, each of which gets its own private index / staging-area, although there are still various bugs (I tripped over one recently).  Git also understands, to some extent, *shallow* repositories where some commits are effectively "missing", and it supports *sparse checkout*, but neither of these help here.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that this is sub-optimal.  The problem is that I'm using a mobile app that needs access to two repos worth of stuff (personal and work todo lists) that *must* live in the same directory on Dropbox (because the mobile app can't handle anything else).  So an unhappy set up with annoyances is probably all I can manage.